# Ready, go! Transparent pop up/ alertView for game

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nstimer, alertview

In my game, I am trying to do a kind of alertView thing that says "Ready?" And then changes to "Go!" After one second. I tried to do this with an alertView but I don't know how to make the alertView title change after one second, or how to make an alertView green when it says go. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: if you're trying to modify `UIAlertView` then **don't**. Make your own `UIView` and modify it to your hearts contents. **Reason...** `UIAlertView` is **not** modifiable and if you **do manage** to hack it then it most likely could get rejected by Apple. **Plus...** a `UIView` is much more customizable and will save you alot more time than hacking around with a `UIAlertView`

Comment: I appreciate it. Should I make a class for my UIView?

Comment: It would be better if you create a `UIView` in the same class. No need for a separate `UIView` class. But... you can, your wish.